# 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python

I've been getting this error when I run the code and I don't understand why. I tried printing the variable 'j' but it does have a non-null value.

Here's the traceback:

```
[array([  0.,  10.]), array([ 0.  ,  0.59]), array([ 0.  ,  1.35]), array([ 0.,  1.])]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model.py", line 300, in <module>
    main()
  File "model.py", line 293, in main
    training(model, data)   
  File "model.py", line 272, in training
    [lambdas, clus, conn] = model.learn(j,env)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

From the function training(model,data):

```
for j in trainingblock:
        print j
        [res,prob,outunits,outacts,act,dist] = model.stimulate(j, env)
        if res == True:
            nitemscorrect += 1
            accuracy = 1
            [lambdas, clus, conn] = model.learn(j,env)
        else:
            accuracy = 0
```

Comment: What is `trainingblock`? Is it `None`?

Comment: @LutzHorn It's a list of lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error occurs here:

```
[lambdas, clus, conn] = model.learn(j,env)
```

Python is attempting to unpack the value returned by `learn` into the three left-hand variables. However, the function has returned `None` and thus python cannot assign values to these variables and raises an exception.

```
x, y, z = [1, 2, 3] # works
x, y, z = None # error
```